# GeneratePasswordResetToken in AspNetSqlMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider

In SimpleMembershipProvider that comes with ASP.NET Razor it's possible to call GeneratePasswordResetToken, then email generated token to the user's email. Then, when the user clicks on the URL, it takes them to a page to reset password.

What is the equivalent workflow in AspNetSqlMembershipProvider? Is it possible to generate a token that can then be used to reset the password?

Thanks.